# force cakephp 3 auth->user() to show virtual fields

Tags: cakephp, authentication, field, virtual, cakephp-3.0

I have a user entity with accessor

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
class User extends Entity {
   protected $_accessible = [
       'email' => true,
       'username' => true,
       'password' => true,
   ];
   protected function _getFullname() {
       return $this->_properties['firstname'] . '  ' .$this->_properties['lastname'];
   }
}
```

when I print

```
$user->fullname
```

in view it works properly
but how can I get fullname in result of

```
pr($this->Auth->user());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** The problem has been fixed in the core, the authentication adapter now fetches entities and converts them via `toArray()`, so that possible virtual fields are being included, given that they are defined in the `$_virtual` property as noted below.

---

The problem here is the authentication adapter, it fetches the user data without hydration, ie it will receive just a raw array with the actually existing columns, not an entity that it could transform into an array afterwards, which would make it possible to include virtual fields.

See **[BaseAuthenticate::_findUser()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/0e90d71732992dd1ab0320c8205e84d13d936da5/src/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L120-L123)**

So at this point, the easiest, yet kinda dirty workaround, would be to fetch the user afterwards again (for example in a [**custom authentication adapter**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects), or in your login action), this time with hydration, and overwrite the user data with the data retrieved from the entity.

Note that if you use `Entity::toArray()`, you'll have to expose the virtual property in order for it to be included in the results:

```
protected $_virtual = ['fullname'];
```

See **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-properties**

It might be worth [**creating an issue over at github**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), maybe changing the base authentication adapter to fetch the data from an entity so that such virtual fields would be included, is something that make sense.